# What is the default covariance structure in glmer and can I change it?

Tags: r, mixed-model, covariance-matrix

For R, I understand that the package lme4 and the function glmer roughly corresponds to glimmix in SAS.  What is the default covariance structure when fit and can it be changed?  If so how?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/how-to-choose-nlme-or-lme4-r-library-for-mixed-effects-models/5350#5350

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about SAS, but variance in `glmer` is controlled by `family` argument. If you want to change correlation structure then I suspect you will have to use `nlme` from **nlme** package.