# Non-linear model in lme4

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm about to attempt to fit a non-linear mixed effects model $(A + B*e^t)$ in lme4. I've already tried fitting this model in nlme with some difficulty due to noise within the data. However, I understand that lme4 has more robust algorithms that's able to better fit non-linear models such as the one written above.

I've ready a few posts such as [How to choose nlme or lme4 R library for mixed effects models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/how-to-choose-nlme-or-lme4-r-library-for-mixed-effects-models)

My question: Is lme4 better than nlme with non-linear models? (nlme vs nlmer)

Comment: What are your criteria for "better"?

Comment: @goangit, By "better", is it more flexible in terms of convergence and fitting of models to data that has a lot of noise? I've noticed that the nlme algorithm is not as flexible and I've had great difficulty with fitting models to noisy data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know if this is discussed or formerly covered elsewhere, but the major differences are:

- **structure in residuals** (favours `nlme`): as with the `lme` vs. `lmer` comparison, `nlme` can be used in conjunction with the package's `corStruct` and `varStruct` capabilities to fit models with autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity
- **documentation** (favours `nlme`): `nlme` is well-documented in Pinheiro and Bates's 2000 Springer book.
- **fixed-effects structure** (`nlme`): `nlme` makes it (much) easier to include non-trivial fixed effects in the model.  As documented [here](http://www.rpubs.com/bbolker/3423), it is theoretically possible but quite difficult to include fixed effects; this is in large part because the derivatives have to be explicitly specified for `nlmer`.
- **speed**, capability for **crossed random effects** (`nlmer`): the machinery underlying `nlmer` is more sophisticated/modern than that of `nlme`, which suggests that it should be faster and possibly more stable for large problems.

Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: thanks for your comments. Indeed, I totally agree with your comment about the documentation-I chose nlme initially partly because of the Bates book. So far, non linear modelling is not well documented in lme4-still looking for resources that can help me understand the syntax, etc. Thanks for the comments too-I think I'll give it a go. If you're aware of any books or documents on non-linear modelling in lme4, I would be very interested in having a look at them.