# Autoregressive covariance structure for linear mixed models in lme4

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

It is straightforward to specify an autoregressive random effects covariance structure using the `nlme` package in `R`, but, it seems to be unavailable in the `lme4` package, at least according to a comment on the selected answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/how-to-choose-nlme-or-lme4-r-library-for-mixed-effects-models), although that comment was from 2010.

Is it possible because of advances in `lme4` or through another approach to specify an autoregressive random effects covariance structure in `lme4`?

Comment: As far as I know, it's still not possible. What kind of model are you fitting that nlme isn't suitable?

Comment: Thanks. I just started using `lme4` (instead of `nlme`). Maybe I should use `nlme` instead, then.